# c# working with databases rather than use visual studio generated code

Tags: c#, database

Well I have been programming odd applications in C# for awhile. I am fairly adaptable to any language. That being said I am by no means an expert. I can get done what I need to and it is fairly clean. The one area that perplexes me is working with database. I understand how databases work and even write some SQL queries. The biggest trouble I have is I use visual studio to auto generate code and it was mentioned in a previous question to stop using that. Well the time has come that I believe it will be beneficial for me to learn the basics of connection to a database and creating the auto generated code that visual studio usually handles. Can anyone here provide me with a place to best learn this? I want something that will guide me on best practices for performance and clean up not just how to make it work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just start with some tutorials from a quick Google search. But this type of question is off topic here unfortunately.

Comment: There is some documentation with example code on the MSDN site, e.g. for [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx).  Try the sample code at the end.  There are different classes to help you with queries versus non-query statements.  There are adapters you can fill with data.  The "Sql" versions work with MS SQL Server, and then there are OracleConnection and OdbcConnection versions of the same classes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want auto-generated code, are you wanting Entity Framework Code First? I noticed you didn't specify.

This is the official documentation for Entity Framework.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907

I'd focus on the Code-first portions and probably don't even worry about the EF Designer, Model First, or Database First in there.

Some key concepts you want to make sure you understand.

- Code First
- Fluent API
- Scaffolding
- Data Annotations
- Migrations